# Email sent from Rails to yahoo users not delivered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, yahoo-mail

I'm facing following issue:

I send emails from rails using Mailer, **it goes fine to all** recipients except users with xxx.yahoo.com account.

I tried sending it using SMPT of

1. Gmail
2. SendGrid

In none of the case it is delivered.

It gives me following error message

> 554 Message not allowed - [PH01] Email not accepted for policy
>   reasons. Please visit
>   https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN5067.html [120]

And when I open their provided link, I see following:

> You'll receive an SMTP error or failed delivery message that includes
>   "554 Message not allowed" when the content of a message you're trying
>   to send violates Yahoo Mail policies. Content that violates policies
>   includes; objectionable links, malicious attachments, or bad header
>   information.

They mentioned about content, so I tried sending simple email (note same email when sent from Mail(mac) client, goes fine)

> Hello Mr. Suraj,
> How are you? Not heard from you for long
>   time.
> See you soon.

So, this doesn't looks related to content, so `bad header information` ?

If its so then, doesn't it a Rails/Mailers issue?

I don't understand how to fix this, any one came across this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of `emails` are you sending and are you sending `bulk` emails ?

Comment: User registration emails such as verification links, password reset links. But for testing I tried even simple emails as mentioned above.

#2 - No bulk emails.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Sending/Help-with-554-Message-not-allowed/m-p/198753/highlight/true#M31649) answer, it might help.